# IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2027' ('MQRC_MISSING_REPLY_TO_Q') Exception With Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a spring boot application which uses JMS template to communicate with queue services.

Here is my producer definition:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
            <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
                <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
                <property name="queueManager" value="${queueManager}"/>
                <property name="hostName" value="${connName}"/>
                <property name="port" value="${connPort}" />
                <property name="channel" value="${channel}"/>
            </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="messageConverter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- JMS outbound gateway -->
<int-jms:outbound-gateway
        id="myJmsOutboundGateway"
        connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
        request-destination-expression="headers.request_destination_queue"
        request-channel="jmsOutboundRequestChannel"     
        reply-destination-expression="headers.reply_destination_queue"
        reply-channel="jmsOutboundReplyChannel"
        explicit-qos-enabled="true"/>
```

Here is consumer definition which stays in other project to listen queue:

```
<!-- Transation flow start -->
<bean id="inboundQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${queueManager}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="#{'inQueue'}"/>
    <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
</bean>
 
<int:channel id="jmsOutboundChannel" />
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="acquirerOutboundAdapter"
        destination-name="destinationQueue"
        jms-template="jmsTemplate"
        channel="jmsOutboundChannel"/>
```

When I run the project and try to send message over IBM MQ, I get this exception:

```
JMS attempted to perform an MQPUT or MQPUT1; however IBM MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2027' ('MQRC_MISSING_REPLY_TO_Q').
                at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:274)
                at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185)
                at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507)
                at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
                at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:691)
                at
```

When we checked headers in message in debug mode, we saw that header which told as missing stays in message headers:

```
jms_destination=queue:///destinationQueue
jms_timestamp=1650004155460
JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28
JMS_IBM_Format=       
id=3d22ed9e-d665-8c9a-7995-bb1a2b0c36eb
acquirerId=404045
jms_messageId=ID:414d5120514d3120202020202020202079ca536203fb1940
JMS_IBM_MsgType=1 
JMSXUserID=mqm        
priority=4
acq_rsp_ts=1650004162979
ReplyToQ=destinationQueue
JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8
JMS_IBM_Encoding=273
reply_destination_queue=destionationQueue
jms_replyTo=queue://QM1/destionationQueue
startTime=1650004162965
JMS_IBM_PutTime=06291556
request_destination_queue=inQueue
JMSXAppID=core.SoftPOSApplication    
jms_redelivered=false
JMS_IBM_PutDate=20220415
jms_correlationId=210595709001
ReplyToQMgr=destinationQueue
```

Why are we facing this problem although header stays in headers? How can we solve this problem?

Comment: You probably need to consult with IBM to determine what is wrong with your requests: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=codes-2027-07eb-rc2027-mqrc-missing-reply-q. It is not clear what is relationship with your `<int-jms:outbound-gateway>` and `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`. Plus that exception says: "Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error". So, what is that? What is linked over there, please?

Comment: @ArtemBilan The linked exception is MQRC_MISSING_REPLY_TO_Q.  Request type messages must have a reply to queue filled in.

Comment: We are putting that fields programmatically when we generating messages:

MessageBuilder<List<InOutElement>> messageBuilder = MessageBuilder.withPayload(dataElements)
        .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
        ...
        .setHeader("ReplyToQ", "queue://QM1/out.queue.name" + message.getHeaders().get("headerName") + queueIdentifierProvider.getQueueIdentifier()) + ...

Comment: Does it matter that ReplyToQ=destinationQueue but reply_destination_queue=destionationQueue and jms_replyTo=queue://QM1/destionationQueue are spelled differently, and also why is ReplyToQMgr=destinationQueue?

Answer (score 0):

If the message type has been set to one of "Request", MQ will check for the presence of a reply to queue in the MQ header; obviously you would want the reply to queue to be present on the queue manager but I don't believe the reply to queue actually has to exist at the time the application puts the message for the put to succeed. Here is a snippet of JMS code that would demonstrate that:

```
Destination sendTo = session.createQueue("IN.Q");                   
Destination replyTo = session.createQueue("IN.Q.REPLY");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(sendTo);
Message msg = session.createTextMessage("test"); 
msg.setIntProperty("JMS_IBM_MsgType",com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants.MQMT_REQUEST);
// Uncomment the line below to prevent a '2027' ('MQRC_MISSING_REPLY_TO_Q') error
// msg.setJMSReplyTo(replyTo); 
producer.send(msg);
```

I appreciate this isn't a complete answer but hopefully it will help you understand what is happening and focus on debugging the Spring configuration.